# xml to oracle conversion

Tags: xml, oracle, altova

I would like to know whether there are any tools which convert xml data into Oracle tables. I came across Altova's MapForce. But I am not sure whether I could use that for achieving this. Could someone suggest any other alternate option / or any help documentation of Mapforce which talks about this conversion.

Thanks,
Shafi

Answer (score 2):

In `10g`, you can create an `XMLType` table and use `SQL*Loader` to load data into it.

See [**documentation**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb25loa.htm) for details.

Then you can fill pure relational tables with `SQL` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The best material I've seen is two papers by Ken Atkins on "Getting XML into and out of Oracle using PL/SQL." There's a version on the ODTUG site (registered members, but registration is free) at http://www.odtug.com/apex/f?p=500:565:0:::::

Comment: Hi Jim,

The above mentioned link is not showing up any content even after I registered. Could you send the link again.

Comment: Yeah, jumping into the middle of the ODTUG site isn't easy. So here's the detailed route: www.odtug.com, click on Tech Resources. In the "search by topic" area click on "PL/SQL". Enter "Atkins" in the search box and it'll be about the 4th item in the list.