# Read data from xml file and populate into oracle table

Tags: java, oracle, dom, sax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xml to oracle conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227259/xml-to-oracle-conversion)

I have xml file which has some records. I want it to store this record into oracle table using Java code. What is the best way to achieve this?

**update**

xml is

```
<Allitems>
    <Item>
        <Thumbnail> ... </Thumbnail>
        <URL> ... </URL>
        <Title> ... </Title>
        <Tag> ... </Tag>
        <Description> ... </Description>
    </Item>

    <Item>
        <Thumbnail> ... </Thumbnail>
        <URL> ... </URL>
        <Title> ... </Title>
        <Tag> ... </Tag>
        <Description> ... </Description>
    </Item>

    ...
    ...

</Allitems>
```

Table has column like

```
thumbnail  
url  
title  
tag and  
description
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227259/xml-to-oracle-conversion

Comment: Depends in what your mapping from data to rows is.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data structure, maybe you don't need DOM, just SAX for XML passing.

When the data is in java side you can send it to database.

IMHO:

> best way

is to subjective and also depends on your context. Maybe your data in xml has 6Tb of data, which needs different approach than 6 records!

Answer (score 0):

In `10g` and higher there is a type called `XMLType`

You can store your XML as an `XMLType` and add data into the columns using `SQL * Loader`

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb25loa.htm